# How to set x and y scroll position on a div with overflow: scroll?

Tags: javascript, html, css

If I have the following markup:-

```css
    .outerDiv {
      width: 500px;
      overflow: scroll;  
    }
    
    .innerDiv {
      width: 1000px;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="outerDiv">
      <div class="innerDiv">
      </div>
    </div>
```

How do I (most likely with JavaScript) set the x and y position of that scroll?

Comment: use **overflow-x: scroll;**  and **overflow-y: scroll;**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use jQuery scrollLeft() and scrollTop() methods.

```
$('.outerDiv').scrollLeft(300);
$('.outerDiv').scrollTop(50);
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/upwrrj70/

Comment: Or you can use scrollTo(), check [this](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/)

Comment: Note there's no jQuery tag on his question

Answer (score 57):

You can use `scrollLeft` and `scrollTop` properties. Ex:

```
document.getElementById("yourScrollElementId").scrollTop = 100
```

Or you can use jquery methods to make it easier and animated as well.

Answer (score 0):

A working example:

```js
document.getElementById('mySection').scrollTop = 50
```

```css
section {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  
  overflow-y: scroll;
  max-height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<section id="mySection">
  <div>foo 1</div>
  <div>foo 2</div>
  <div>foo 3</div>
  <div>foo 4</div>
  <div>foo 5</div>
  <div>foo 6</div>
  <div>foo 7</div>
  <div>foo 8</div>
  <div>foo 9</div>
</section>
```