# Is there a way of setting the horizontal scroll position of a div to the middle on load?

Tags: html, css

I have a div with a 100vw width, then inside it another div with 150vw width inside it with overflow-x set to scroll. Ideally I want this inner div to sit in the middle on the parent on load and then allow the user to scroll either way they want. Any ideas?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41218818/how-to-set-x-and-y-scroll-position-on-a-div-with-overflow-scroll

Answer (score 0):

Its good to write your code for making your question clear.
But you can use Javascript:

```
window.onload = function() {
  var elmnt = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  elmnt.scrollLeft += 100;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) 
With some assumptions about your code, you may want to do something like this

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  document.querySelector('.inner-div').scrollLeft = document.querySelector('.outer-div').innerWidth / 2
})
```