# Scroll to pageY in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

When you clicked somewhere on a page, you'll get a PointerEvent, which contains pageY or layerY, meaning a px size from the top of the page.

Well, the above is for to "get" the info, but how do you "set" a pageY to scroll to the position where pageY sized below the top? Thanks.

Comment: I think this question should help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41218818/how-to-set-x-and-y-scroll-position-on-a-div-with-overflow-scroll

Comment: As for the downvoter they probably thought that this question lacks some research, well 
— although I already know the answer to your question – I did google and surprisingly found it hard to find the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for [scrollTo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo)

```
window.scrollTo(X, Y)
```